# OR criteria Grails nested objects

Tags: grails, criteria

I'm trying to use createCriteria with OR on two nested objects.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
or {
  ordersSecondaryReceptionSystem {
    eq('code', params.receptionSystemCode)
  }
  ordersReceptionSystem {
    eq('code', params.receptionSystemCode)
  }
}
```

Only one of the two are being taken into account, the secondary one.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Without knowing more about your domain objects it's hard to say much for sure.  You can turn up logging to see the exact SQL being generated, which is often helpful for these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by creating an Alias:

```
createAlias('ordersReceptionSystem', 'ordersReceptionSystem', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
                    createAlias('ordersSecondaryReceptionSystem', 'ordersSecondaryReceptionSystem', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
                    or {
                        eq('ordersReceptionSystem.code', params.receptionSystemCode)
                        eq('ordersSecondaryReceptionSystem.code', params.receptionSystemCode)
                    }
```